# Transportation request form date/time issue

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-calendar-api, google-forms

We have a transportation request form that is used to assign vehicles.  It also populates a calendar to keep up with which vehicles are being used on which day.  Issue, if the time and date of the "return details" aren't after the "departure details" it throws an error and the calendar item creation function won't run.

ex. 12am is an issue for some.  They may put...depart 1/20 4pm, return 1/20 12am.  Which is actually before departure.  Other times they simply put the wrong dates from being in a hurry.

I would like to check that part of the submission, if there is an error send and edit url link in an email back to the requestor with instructions to fix.

Any help on this would be appreciated.

```
function createCalEvent(){
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheetName);
var headers = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues(); 
var columnIndex = headers[0].indexOf(calendarColumnName);
var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
var form = FormApp.openById(formURL);
var emailAddress = "transportation@.net";
var myCal = CalendarApp.getCalendarById('transportation@.net');
for(var i = startRow-1; i < data.length; i++) {
if(data[i][0] != '' && data[i][columnIndex] == '') {
  var timestamp = Utilities.formatDate(data[i][0], 'CST', 'MMMM dd, yyyy h:mm a');
  var staffName = data[i][1];
  var departureDate = Utilities.formatDate(data[i][2],'CST', "EEEE, MMMM dd, yyyy");
  var departureTime = Utilities.formatDate(data[i][3], 'CST', "h:mm a");
  var returnDate = Utilities.formatDate(data[i][4],'CST', "EEEE, MMMM dd, yyyy");
  var returnTime = Utilities.formatDate(data[i][5],'CST', "h:mm a");
  var destination = data[i][6];
  var groupAttending = data[i][7];
  var reasonForTrip = data[i][8];
  var teacherInCharge = data[i][9];
  var specialRequest = data[i][10];
  var vehicleOneAssigned = data[i][11];
  var vehicleTwoAssigned = data[i][12];
  var originalEmail = data[i][13];
  var numberOfPassengers = data[i][14];
  var requestorEmailAddress = data[i][15];
  var pdfUrlLink = data[i][40];
  var editURL = data[i][41];
  if(pdfUrlLink != ''){

  var title = staffName + '-' + destination + '-' + vehicleOneAssigned;
  var descriptionList = 'Group Attending: ' + groupAttending + '<br> Number of Passengers: ' + numberOfPassengers + '<br> Reason For Trip: ' + reasonForTrip + '<br> Teacher In Charge: ' + teacherInCharge + '<br> Special Request: ' + specialRequest + '<br> Request Link: ' + pdfUrlLink;
  var event = myCal.createEvent(title,
                            new Date(departureDate + ' ' + departureTime),
                            new Date(returnDate + ' ' + returnTime),
                                  {description: descriptionList});

    var eventID = event.getId();
    Logger.log('Calendar Calendar Event ID: ' + eventID);
    sheet.getRange(i+1, columnIndex+1).setValue(eventID);

      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Please share relevant code and exact wording of any errors.  Also take a look at [ask] and [mcve].

Comment: Errors:1/9/19 4:27 PM createCalEvent Event start time must be before event end time. (line 209, file "Code") time-based 1/9/19 4:27 PM

Comment: Doesn't it seem reasonable to require event end time to be after event start  time.  What's the problem?

Comment: It looks like you need to insure the end time is after start time in your code but we can't help you with that because you haven't supplied any code. [mcve]

Comment: I'd like them to fix their own error before createCalEvent script runs.  I need help scripting a validation step, return error to requestor via email and have them fix their error.

Comment: Are you using a Google Form?

Comment: Yes, thanks for helping.

Comment: I don't use Google Forms myself.  This would be an easy matter for clientside validation in javascript in a standard webapp.  At this point, I suppose that I'd consider capturing the incoming data with an "onFormSubmit" and insuring that end time is after start time and sending the users and email letting them know that their submission was rejected.  Not being a user of Google Forms I can't say for sure but I would have expected there to be some manner of clientside validation for this sort of situation.  Perhaps other volunteers here will have a better answer.

Comment: Thanks, I will keep looking for solutions and waiting on other volunteers.